# Would like to create a sort of "active-filter" shortcut

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

What I'm envisioning is -

I have 2 sheets of data currently. In Sheet 1 I have rows of data, at the end of each row of data I would like to have an active option like a button or link that when clicked/activated will bring the user straight to the data in Sheet 2.

There is also one more condition in that this link/button when activated will also filter the data in Sheet 2 based off a value in its corresponding row.

For example:

[Sheet 1]

Row 1 - CriteriaX........ButtonX
Row 2 - CriteriaY........ButtonY
Row 3 - CriteriaZ........ButtonZ

Clicking on either of the buttons will bring the user straight to the data in Sheet 2 already filtered by the corresponding Criteria.

Is there a way to do this?

Appreciate any advice!

Warmest regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

You can assign Google Apps Script functions to buttons by clicking the three dots menu and selecting `Assign Script`:

[image]

Then you can put the function name in the dialog box.

Actually you have to do this for **every** row as per your original proposal, which becomes repetitive quickly as you add more rows. To solve this, you can use only one button, and the selected cell becomes the filter criteria.

As for the code itself, you need to use the **[Filter](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter)** class to define filters for ranges.

```
function createFilter() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var criteriaValue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue();
  var sheet2 = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var range = sheet2.getRange(1,1,sheet2.getLastRow(),sheet2.getLastColumn());
  if (range.getFilter() != null) {
    range.getFilter().remove();
  }
  if (criteriaValue != '') {
    range.createFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(1, 
      SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
        .whenTextEqualTo(criteriaValue)
        .build()
    );
  }
  ss.setActiveSheet(sheet2);
}
```

**Sample Output:**

Filtering by Product A:

[image]

Filtered Table after clicking button:

[image]

Comment: Hi Carlos, thanks for this, it works great! On another note, I decided to go with a single button as you mentioned, but as the sheet scrolls on downwards, it will inevitably get lost on top. Is there a way to "lock" the button or incorporate the script within a cell so that it can be reproduced in future rows?

Comment: You can freeze the top row in View menu -> Freeze -> 1 row